# Elasticsearch equivalent to WHERE x = 1 AND (y = 2 OR y = 3)

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm looking for an equivalent to the following pseudocode:

```
SELECT id, age                                  // works
  FROM students                                 // works
 WHERE firstname = 'John'                       // works
   AND gender = 'm'                             // works   
   AND (lastname = 'Doe' OR lastname = 'Wayne') // no idea
```

My current code:

```
{
    // ...
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [
                { match: { firstname: 'John' }},
                { match: { gender: 'm' }},
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with the `OR`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
{ match: { lastname: /^(Doe|Wayne)$/ }}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all as the match query doesn't support regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
{
    // ...
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [
                { match: { firstname: 'John' }},
                { match: { gender: 'm' }},
                {
                  bool: {
                    minimum_should_match: 1, 
                    should: [
                      { match: { lastname: 'Doe' }},
                      { match: { lastname: 'Wayne' }}
                    ]
                  }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```